# jQuery wrapAll two element with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two variables `currentSectionElement` and `sectionList`.

They looks like:

```
currentSectionElement = $("<div>current</div>");
sectionList = $("<div>sectionList</div>");
```

I want to display it like this:

```
<div>
    <div>current</div>
    <div>sectionList</div>
<div>
```

So, I've tried following way:

```
currentSectionElement.after(sectionList); 
$(currentSectionElement, sectionList).wrapAll('<div></div>');
```

However it becomes:

```
<div>
    <div>current</div>
<div>
<div>sectionList</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.add()` to combine the `currentSectionElement` and `sectionList` into a jQuery object then use .`wrapAll()`

```js
var currentSectionElement = $("<div>current</div>");
var sectionList = $("<div>sectionList</div>");

var newObj = currentSectionElement.add(sectionList);
newObj.wrapAll('<div></div>').parent().appendTo(document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

You can create another `div` and use `append()`

```js
var currentSectionElement = $("<div>current</div>");
var sectionList = $("<div>sectionList</div>");

var newObj = currentSectionElement.add(sectionList);
$('<div>').append(newObj).appendTo(document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! But is it possible to use `wrapAll`?

Comment: @CodaChang, Updated

Comment: @CodaChang: Yes, it is. Not necessarily better, but it is.

Answer (score 1):

```js
currentSectionElement = $("<div>current</div>");
sectionList = $("<div>sectionList</div>");

$('body').append('<div class=red></div>');
$('body').find('div').append(currentSectionElement).append(sectionList)
```

```css
.red{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Why not append an empty div then in that empty div append both divs

```js
currentSectionElement = $("<div>current</div>");
sectionList = $("<div>sectionList</div>");


$('body').append(currentSectionElement).append(sectionList)
$('body').find('div').wrapAll('<div class=red></div>');
```

```css
.red{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you want wrap all append both in append then use `wrapApp()`

Comment: Thanks, great example!

Answer (score 1):

`$(currentSectionElement, sectionList)` doesn't create a jQuery set containing the intersection of `currentSectionElement` and `sectionList`. To do that, you use `currentSectionElement.add(sectionList)`.

If you do that, your `wrapAll` works:

```js
currentSectionElement = $("<div>current</div>");
sectionList = $("<div>sectionList</div>");

currentSectionElement.add(sectionList)
  .wrapAll("<div></div>")
  .parent()
  .appendTo(document.body);
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your grate explanation, I got it.